# Fashion Mnist Tensorflow Data Shape Incompatibility

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, tf.data.dataset

I know that there are similar questions. Although I have checked them, I did not solve my problem.

I tried to implement mini-batching on fashion-Mnist dataset. Therefore I converted the dataset from np.array to tensor with `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices` but I could not solve the data shape incompatibility problem. Here is my code:

**Loading Data**

```
(train_images, train_labels) , (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

**Converting to tf.Dataset:**

```
 train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, train_labels))
 test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_images, test_labels))
```

**My model**

```
model_1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = [28,28]),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation = "relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation = "relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = "softmax"),
    
])

model_1.compile( loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
               optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
               metrics = ["accuracy"])

info = model_1.fit(train_ds,
                  epochs = 10,
                  validation_data = (test_images, test_labels))
```

**But that gives me this error:**

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784 but received input with shape [28, 28]
```

**I checked the input shape with the following code: (Output is [28, 28])**

```
list(train_ds.as_numpy_iterator().next()[0].shape)
```

How can I solve this problem, I would appreciate if you could help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `tf.data.Dataset` API for feeding your model, you should define the batch_size from the dataset.

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, train_labels)).batch(256)
test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_images, test_labels)).batch(256)
```

Now you can use both datasets to train your model like:

```
info = model_1.fit(x=train_ds, epochs = 10, validation_data=test_ds)
```